# How to upgrade Dell Latitude 630 (laptop) firmware?

Tags: bios

I just got a brand new 250GB hard drive for a laptop, Dell Latitude 630 that could not be recognized. I am guessing the 250GB could be large and needs BIOS upgrade.

I need help to locate the BIOS upgrade software download, I don’t just want to download any junk over the internet.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason you woudl need to upgrade your BIOS firmware to see a drive that small.

Comment: @Ramhound Older computers may have problems with drives >=128GB

Comment: @kinokijuf - This isn't that old of a laptop.  It came with `Windows 7` and was released in 2011.

Comment: you could try the dell website... alternatively, the brand new hard drive could be broken, maybe test it on another machine?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try re-installing the drive and/or updating the BIOS with one from Dell's support site, as suggested in the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Dell Latitute D630, it came out around 2007. The support [site is here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-d630/) and the BIOS is available from the above site.

These came originally with 80GB drives I believe. Amazon has a 250GB drive listed for the D630.

You could certainly try updating the BIOS to address your issue but as others have stated it seems unlikely this is the problem at hand.

It is likely a problem with the drive or the installation of the drive. I would take it out and if you have the old drive and it was working replace the old drive and see what happens. If the old drive works, then put in the new drive again. Or if you don't have a working old drive, put the new drive back in.

If you have another system with a compatible drive, you could try it as well.

Lastly you might test your new drive in another system. Depending on what systems you have you might need to pickup an inexpensive external case for it or just get an inexpensive adapter.